# Form Doesn't Send Values Or PHP Code Doesn't Update

Tags: php

FORM

```
<form method="post" action="menu_duzenle_islem.php">
Şuanki İsim : <input name="menu_isim" value="<?php echo $_POST['menu_isim'] ?>"readonly>
Yeni İsim : <input name="yeni_menu_isim" placeholder="isim giriniz.">
Şuanki URL : <input name="menu_url" value="<?php echo $_POST['menu_url'] ?>"readonly>
Yeni URL : <input name="yeni_menu_url" placeholder="url giriniz">
<input type="submit" value="Düzenle">
</form>
```

menu_duzenle_islem.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mmogezgini");
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE menuler SET isim='$_POST[yeni_menu_isim]' and url='$_POST[yeni_menu_url]'
WHERE isim='$_POST[menu_isim]' AND url='$_POST[menu_url]'");
mysqli_close($con);
Header("Location:menuler.php");
?>
```

when i update "menu_isim" and "menu_url" menu_isim showing "0" and menu_url doesn't change.

Comment: MySQLi supports multiple statements per query. If you dont escape/bind/prepare your parameters, this is easy way to SQL inject and drop or change all your tables

Comment: not only is this bad practice syntax: `"'$_POST[menu_isim]'"`, use this: `"..." . $_POST['menu_isim'] . "...."`

Comment: @DanFromGermany Thank you for advice i will search for escape function right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL query is not correct, refer the following:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE menuler SET isim='". $_POST['yeni_menu_isim']."' ,url='".$_POST['yeni_menu_url'] ."'
WHERE isim='".$_POST['menu_isim']."' AND url='".$_POST['menu_url']."'");
```

Comment: Thanks it works but why people downvote me this is not for ask what you dont know and answer what you know for helping each other? a time later i will couldn't ask questions :(